# Changing the model does not redraw objects in QML sometimes

Tags: c++, qml, repeater

```
            Repeater {
                model: myModel.buttonParameters
                delegate: Button
                {
                    width: 47
                    height:  47
                    contentItem: Text {
                        id: content
                        text: modelData.name
                        font.family: MyStyle.fontFamily
                        fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
                        font.pixelSize: 30
                        font.styleName: "Bold"
                        topPadding: height / 6
                        color: modelData.visibility ? MyStyle.colorFromSeriesName(this.text) : MyStyle.dividerColor
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    }

                    background: Rectangle
                    {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        radius: 4
                        color: MyStyle.backgroundColor
                        border.color:MyStyle.dividerColor
                        border.width: 2
                    }

                    onClicked: {
                        cntModel.visibilityOfChartChanged(modelData.name, "plot");
                    }
                }
            }
            
            On the C++ side.
            myModel.buttonParameters is a QList<MyModel*> , where MyModel is a class inherited from QObject.
            
           Q_PROPERTY(QVariant buttonParameters READ buttonParametersList NOTIFY buttonParametersChanged)

           QVariant buttonParametersList()
          {
             return QVariant::fromValue(m_buttonParametersList );
          }
```

The problem is that with a certain change in the model
(the signal buttonParametersChanged is sent), namely,
if the number of objects was equal to one and after the update there
is also one object, but with different characteristics, no redrawing
takes place, the old button remains. Moreover, it somehow depends on
the runtime. Also, if I remove the line with color, the model will update.

Comment: I wonder if I change text: modelData.name to  myModel.buttonParameters[index].name, modelData.visibility to myModel.buttonParameters[index].visibility,  everything will work, the buttons will redraw with new text and color. It turns out that the problem is in modelData , but why?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that buttonParametersChanged is a signal that triggers on the assignment of a new container (QList<>) to buttonParameters. It doesn't trigger on changes to the *contents* of an existing QList<> assigned to that property.

However, you can always manually trigger buttonParametersChanged when you know you've modified the contents of the QList<> which should give you the effect you want.

Note, a QML ListModel or C++ equivalent would likely be more appropriate for this use case. Many QML components are designed to specifically integrate with them and handle the cases of container contents changing.

Comment: That's the thing, I call the signal buttonParametersChanged manually, and in certain situations it doesn't work

Comment: I'd add an onButtonParametersChanged handler that logs out something so you can make sure that signal is really firing when you think it is.

Comment: The signal is definitely fired, I checked.

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example in this case